# Force IE9 to emulate IE8. Possible?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, ie8-compatibility-mode, x-ua-compatible

Is this possible at all?
I tried adding this to the page but it didn't change a thing.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

UPDATE- I'm trying to do this because our site has some IE9 specific CSS issues, which wouldn't appear in IE8.

Thanks

Comment: IE9 is not finished yet - maybe they will release this sort of information upon final release.

Comment: There's a few IE9 specific CSS issues on our site, which don't appear in IE8.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> You can use the document compatibility
>   mode to do this, which is what you
>   were trying.. However, thing to note
>   is: It must appear in the Web page's
>   header (the HEAD section) before all
>   other elements, except for the title
>   element and other meta elements Hope
>   that was the issue.. Also, The
>   X-UA-compatible header is not case
>   sensitive Refer:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode

Edit: in case something happens to kill the msdn link, here is the content:

> Specifying Document Compatibility Modes
>
> You can use document modes to control the way Internet Explorer
>   interprets and displays your webpage. To specify a specific document
>   mode for your webpage, use the meta element to include an
>   X-UA-Compatible header in your webpage, as shown in the following
>   example.
>
> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>   <!-- Enable IE9 Standards mode -->
>   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
>   <title>My webpage</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <p>Content goes here.</p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> If you view this webpage in Internet Explorer 9, it will be displayed
>   in IE9 mode.
>
> The following example specifies EmulateIE7 mode.
>
> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>   <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
>   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
>   <title>My webpage</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <p>Content goes here.</p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> In this example, the X-UA-Compatible header directs Internet Explorer
>   to mimic the behavior of Internet Explorer 7 when determining how to
>   display the webpage. This means that Internet Explorer will use the
>    directive (or lack thereof) to choose the appropriate
>   document type. Because this page does not contain a 
>   directive, the example would be displayed in IE5 (Quirks) mode.

Comment: That did the trick, it had to be the first element inside the head tag.

Comment: The link was just for props really, the actual information is all in the msdn link.

Answer (score 26):

Yes. Recent versions of IE (IE8 or above) let you adjust that. Here's how:

- Fire up Internet Explorer.
- Click the 'Tools' menu, then click 'Developer Tools'. Alternatively, just press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

That should open the Developer Tools window. That window has two menu items that are of interest:

- **Browser Mode.** This setting determines the value of the user-agent header sent for every request.
- **Document Mode.** This setting determines how the rendering engine renders the page.

More at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx

Comment: I knew about this, but I was trying to make the page render in IE8 mode for all visitors, not just for me when debugging. Thanks though

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

The 1st element as in no hard returns. A hard return I guess = an empty node/element in the DOM which becomes the 1st element disabling the doc compatability meta tag.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side you can add and remove **websites** to be displayed in Compatibility View from **Compatibility View Settings** window of IE:

Tools-> Compatibility View Settings

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly fix the problem, but it is a perfect workaround for our corporate environment with 10+ users who are facing this problem.