# Website appears to be using incorrect version of .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

In certain ASP.Net Ajax callbacks, and only on some servers, I am getting the error

> Error: Unable to get value of the property 'async': object is null or
>   undefined

It appears to me that this is the multiple callback error that was supposed to be fixed in .Net 3.5 SP1 [according to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/260892/fix-for-webform-callbackcomplete), and this is born out by examining the versions of WebForm_CallbackComplete that are generated on the failing servers. This implies that SP1 is not being used by the site, but it *is* installed on the server. How would I verify whether SP1 is being used by the web site, and what needs to be done to upgrade it if it isn't being used?

Thanks!

Comment: @Ben....I believe this is an IE 7 issue.  Are you using IE 7?

Comment: I am my provider. No, this occurs in IE9 as well.

Comment: AFAIK 3.5 SP1 overwrites 3.5, so it can't be using the wrong version. That said IIRC SQL Server has its own embedded .NET that's independent of the system .NET, but I'm pretty sure IIS doesn't do that. You could try a clean reinstall of 3.5SP1?

Comment: Check IIS.  Your ASP.NET may be referring to an an old version.

Comment: @Blam - The properties page in IIS 6 only shows whether you have ASP.Net 1.1 or 2.0. Is there somewhere else to check that shows whether the 3.5 service pack is installed?

Answer (score 0):

@Ben.....This is an IE issue rather than .Net.....

Here's a good link describing the situation:
[Stackoverflow answer IE 9...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787245/ie9-javascript-error-script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-ui-obje)

Comment: I do not believe this is the issue. The implementation of WebForm_CallbackComplete is different on the failing machines than on the successful ones.

Answer (score 0):

Then something is not right as my IIS application under the APS.NET tab has 1, 2, and 4.  In Windows Microsoft.NET Framework you will find a AspNetRegIIS.exe for the various versions.

Comment: .NET 3.0 and 3.5 do not show up under the ASP.NET tab in IIS6, since they all run under the CLR 2.0.

Comment: @mgnoonan I think you care correct.  There is no AspNetRegIIS.exe in 3.0 and 3.5.

Comment: The 3.0 and 3.5 releases were really just additional functionality for 2.0 (and one can argue they did not deserve incrementing the version number to 3.x).

Comment: @mgnoonan Kind of off topic but I hear they are doing the same with 4.5 and with WinRT I would think it deserves a real version.

Comment: Yep, Hanselman has a good blog post explaining it. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx