# Unable to get value of the property 'get': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, magento

my site www.theprinterdepo.com its a magento oscommerce site
As you know its open source, I didnt developed it.

It loads perfect in chrome and firefox, but I am receiving this javascript error in internet explorer 9.

Unable to get value of the property 'get': object is null or undefined

I tried to debug and found that the problem is it prototype.js

prototype.js, line 516 character 1

The line where it fails its:

```
var respondersForEvent=registry.get(eventName);if(Object.isUndefined(respondersForEvent)){respondersForEvent=[];registry.set(eventName,respondersForEvent);}
if(respondersForEvent.pluck('handler').include(ha
```

Obviously, because this is a library, I dont want to modify it my self.

I am looking for suggestions in what to do in this case based on your experience?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787245/ie9-javascript-error-script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-ui-obje

Comment: I have this: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of known issues with Magento and IE9 unfortunately, an accepted solution to the problem issue is to use a meta tag such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Placed immediately after the title tag. See [this blog post](http://blog.gaiterjones.com/magento-internet-explorer-9-ie9/) for more details.

Comment: thanks, at least I dont have the js exception anymore. My site still looks ugly in IE 9.