# Check file size from HTML file input with JQuery and IE9

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I'm using JQuery to check the file size and type on a form file input field. The HTML is:

```
<input name="source" id="imageFile" type="file" style ="border: 1px solid #576675;">
```

and the JQuery:

```
$('#imageFile').bind('change', function() {

   var imageSize = this.files[0].size/1048576;
   var imageType = this.files[0].type.toString();

   //.... checking different condition for imageSize and imageType....///
});
```

The code works on both FireFox and Chrome, but in IE9 I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
```

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery), but is there really no way to do this in IE9 ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to many other issues that you get this error with - of which I've come across also before.
See this SO link - [IE9 JavaScript error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'ui': object is null or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787245/ie9-javascript-error-script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-ui-obje)

I'm quite sure the meta tag solution worked for me. Otherwise you may have to not do certain tasks in IE9 if this solution cannot work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the behavior to IE8, and this functionality doesn't work on IE8 Either.