# IE9 error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'ajax': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, backbone.js

**My problem**

I'm trying to put a map on a webpage, the data being fetch with Ajax. It works fine with all browsers, but not IE9.

I get an error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'ajax': object is null or undefined

and the map does not load.

**The code**

```
       var mapModel = new Map(); 

       mapModel.get("leads").fetch({success: function(){ //error on this line
              var mapView = new MapView({ model: mapModel });
              $('body').append(mapView.el);
              mapView.render();
           }});
```

**What I tried**

This seems to be a very common issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787245/ie9-javascript-error-script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-ui-obje) is the most up-voted question on the subject. So I tried to put

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

but it didn't solve anything.

**My question**

What I should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you include the JQuery? Backbone's fetch() method is delegated to the $.ajax() method. if ajax can't be found on some object, it must be $ is missing.

Comment: I wondered about that too. But why does it work in chrome then?

Comment: On IE9 hit F12 and go to the console, type "$". result is?

Comment: so JQuery is not loaded, try to clear the cache of IE, and check out the configuration about javascript.

Comment: is it work on other browsers? if it works I don't know what's your problem, else it doesn't work then  you need to change inside `fetch`, because it returned something (like json)

Comment: I found the problem, look at my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found the problem:

IE9 was rendering the page in compatibility mode.

I added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

as the very first line of the header, and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I solved this issue.

In my master page, there was a script manager. I replaced it with ToolkitScriptManager which is actually packaged with AjaxControlToolkit 4.0.

Now it works superbly.

Hope this might help someone