# IE11 unable to see JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

In reference to [JavaScript Functions Working Locally but not in Test deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55048839/11035837)

While I have the website functional for Chrome, not all of my users use Chrome.

Some still prefer (or are restricted to) IE11.  IE11, however, cannot execute the JavaScript functions, even when it posts the script for them in the DOM_Explorer and Debugger views.

**What can be done to force IE11 to recognize the JavaScript so that all my users can use the page correctly regardless of browser?**

Comment: IE can execute JS functions just fine, please show an example of the code which is not executed in IE.

Comment: Thanks to @JhWebDevGuy  for showing me this: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48320394/11035837

Answer (score -1):

IE11 doesn't support many of ES6 features. For example [arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions).
If you are using ES6, see [this answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902809/support-for-es6-in-internet-explorer-11).