# Jquery drag drop bug in IE9

Tags: jquery

I’m working on a JQuery "Nettuts drag and drop" from [iNETTUTS demo](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html).

Which I have downloaded from [webdesigner.com](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/).

The demo works excellently in all the browsers except IE9. If anyone has a solution, I would appreciate it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how you fixed this issue? I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use new version of jQuery & UI (works for me jquery 1.6.2 & jquery ui 1.8.14)

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI - Anything above 1.8.5. Drag and Drop IE issue was fixed in Version 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of an IE guy but I suggest you see: [Force IE9 to emulate IE8. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811801/force-ie9-to-emulate-ie8-possible)