# Why does the div with scroll resizes on hover for TH

Tags: html, css

For some reason when I use the hover selector on a TH inside a div with a scroll, the parent div resizes. Every time the mouse over effect is triggered the div grows by one line.

I tested this in other browsers but I can only reproduce this in IE 9. Anyone have a way to resolve this?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9" />
<style>
    .testScroller {
        max-width: 200px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .testHeader:hover { 
        background-color: lightBlue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="testScroller">
        <table >
            <tr >
                <th class="testHeader">header 0</th>
                <th class="testHeader">header 1</th>
                <th class="testHeader">header 2</th>
                <th class="testHeader">header 3</th>
                <th class="testHeader">header 4</th>
                <th class="testHeader">header 5 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td >0</td>
                <td >1</td>
                <td >2</td>
                <td >3</td>
                <td >4</td>
                <td >5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost beautiful in it's bugginess! However, if you change your style to this, it should fix the problem :

```
.testScroller {
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
.testHeader {
    background-color: green;
}
.testHeader:hover { 
    background-color: lightBlue;
}
```

As evidenced by the comments, this is far more complicated than the simple fix belies. This appears to have something to do with IE9 having broken something - this works ok in IE8.

Check out this question : [Force IE9 to emulate IE8. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811801/force-ie9-to-emulate-ie8-possible)

Which will lead you to changing your meta tag to this :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Comment: My actual CSS is more complex. That CSS I posted was the simplest code I could use to reporduce the issue. 

    .testScroller {
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: green;
 }
 .testHeader {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: White;
  background-color: green;
 }
 .testHeader:hover { 
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  color: #1d5987;
 }

Comment: Hm. It's obviously more complex than I thought. What I've written will work but only if you don't try to set any other properties in the hover style. The issue is, as someone else mentioned, caused by the max-width and overflow-x properties which IE 9 doesn't support fully. If you can redesign your CSS without them that may well be a better solution.

Comment: This seems to be caused by some kind of measuring function gone wrong. If you can set a fixed height for your table that will also make the issue go away.

Comment: I believe the person who said max-width and overflow-x is incorrect. I looked in to it and they both are fully supported. That is probably why the comment was removed.

Comment: The number of row in my application changes. so i do not have a fixed height

Comment: Hm. Even replacing the max-width and overflow-x with width and overflow still causes the bug, surprisingly. Adding *any* extra property to the hover style causes it to happen...very weird bug, possibly easier to design around than try to find a fix for.

Answer (score 4):

You should add:

```
.testScroller {
    overflow-x: auto;
    min-height:0%   /* IE9 fix */
}
```

See this link for details

http://blog.brianrichards.net/post/6721471926/ie9-hover-bug-workaround

Answer (score 1):

Taking adhocgeek suggestion of using a set height I did this.  Gave ID to the object and ran this JQuery on load. Feels hacky but it works for now. I needed to add in the 30 to give space for the scroll bar.

```
$("#testScroller").height($("#testTable").height() + 30);
```

Also whatever is causing this has been resolved in IE10.

If you set the height to itself the problem is fixed

```
$("#testScroller").height(($("#testScroller").height()))
```

Comment: I also found out if I set the height to the current height on load the problem is resolved.
        $("#testScroller").height(($("#testScroller").height()));

Answer (score 1):

I had this resizing on hover problem with IE 11. To solve it, I changed `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow-y: scroll;`, then it worked.
The reason is IE 11 doesn't support the two value `overflow` shorthand.